# VBA Excel date yyyy/mmm/dd to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: excel, format, date-format, vba

I'm writing small VBA to manage and convert some date from external tables and I'm stuck on some strange date format like: yyyy/mm/dd
What I really need is to convert date from a1 and paste it to b2

As a tamplate I will use to columns A1 and B1:
A1= date to be converted B1= Paste Destinaton of converted dat

- a1
- 2012.Jan.04
- 2012.Nov.04
- 2012.Dct.04

  - b1
  - 04.01.2012
  - 04.11.2012
  - 04.12.2012

What I tested for now is:

1. Formula to convert (with created dictionary) - Cannot use it in case
   of many dates to convert
2. VBA for date convert - Cannot see my date from A1 as a proper date
   and do nothing
3. Format this date in excel build-in function "formating" - Do nothing
4. Also function "text-to-column" was tested - Still do nothing

It is looking like I'm just stuck on something really simple but it is really an hard to move forward for now so this is why I'm asking for help.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following formula in `B1`:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MATCH(MID(A1,6,3),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dct"},0),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

What looks strange is the abbreviation "Dct" for December. So maybe you have to change the array Literal `{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dct"}` according to your language.

Using `VBA` following `Function` could be used:

```
Function convert_YYYY_MMM_DD_Text2Date(sText As String) As Variant
 Dim iYear As Integer
 Dim iMonth As Integer
 Dim sMonth As String
 Dim iDay As Integer
 Dim aMonths As Variant
 Dim bFound As Boolean

 aMonths = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dct")

 On Error GoTo errHandler
 iYear = CInt(Left(sText, 4))
 sMonth = Mid(sText, 6, 3)
 iDay = CInt(Right(sText, 2))

 For iMonth = 0 To UBound(aMonths)
  If aMonths(iMonth) = sMonth Then
   bFound = True
   Exit For
  End If
 Next

 If bFound Then
  convert_YYYY_MMM_DD_Text2Date = DateSerial(iYear, iMonth + 1, iDay)
 Else
  GoTo errHandler
 End If

 On Error GoTo 0

 Exit Function

errHandler:
 convert_YYYY_MMM_DD_Text2Date = "conversion not possible"

End Function
```

Comment: Works Perfect. Sometimes Formulas are Stunning what you can do with them.

Comment: Yes it is working and thanks for that. But what is your opinion? What will works faster. Tha VBA code or this formula for ~10 000 rows in my date ?
My procces is looks like:
vba donwload tha data from other workbook then convert it to proper colums that can be uploded to outlook calendar.
All code is working without this date convert step. Of course if i can not find best solution for that I will use formula like i propose.
Many thanks for your support :)

Comment: Supplemented a `VBA` function which takes a string ("YYYY.MMM.DD") and returns either a date or an error string.

Comment: Great Job!
I will implement it to my code and try to remember that way of thinking for the future.
Thanks for your sharing your knowledge.